# Apex class on Lead needs to review

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, code

Requirement--

I have one custom Object(Lead_map__c) where values are stored Like leadSource={'Web','Email','Phone'} and respective userIds in userId_assignee__c column

Whenever lead is updated with Checkbox Need Assistance=true then ownerId will be change based on Lead_map__c table
and needs to create and assgine task to owner and
when Lead is updated to false then userid needs to be change with currentUser

I have written a code which is working but if anyone can suggest a best practice or let me know any issue,mistake,any other simple way to write this logic.

```
public class LeadMapHandler {
public static boolean isrun =true;
public static void updateLeadOwner(List<lead> leadList,map<id,lead>oldmap) {
    set<string> leadSource = new set<string>();
    try{
        for(lead l:leadList) {
            leadSource.add(l.leadsource);  //get the source of lead
        }

        map<string,lead_map__c> leadMap = new map<string,lead_map__c>();

        for(lead_map__c lm : [select id,UserId_to_assign__c,Lead_Source__c from Lead_Map__c where Lead_Source__c in:leadSource]) {
            leadMap.put(lm.lead_source__c,lm); 
        }

        List<lead> updateLead = new List<lead>();
        for(lead leadRecord:leadList) {
            lead oldlead =oldmap.get(leadRecord.id);
            if((oldlead.Need_Assistance__c!=leadRecord.Need_Assistance__c) && leadRecord.Need_Assistance__c) {
                if(leadMap.get(leadRecord.LeadSource)!=null) {
                    lead ls = new lead();
                    ls.id=leadRecord.Id;
                    ls.OwnerId =leadMap.get(leadRecord.LeadSource).UserId_to_assign__c;
                    updateLead.add(ls);
                    createTask(leadMap.get(leadRecord.LeadSource).UserId_to_assign__c);  
                }
            }
            else if(leadRecord.Need_Assistance__c== false){
                updateLeadBack(leadRecord);  //call a method to update Owner with CurrentLoged in User
            }    
        }
        if(updateLead.size()>0) {
            update updateLead;
        }
    }
    catch(exception e) {
        system.debug('EXCEPTION OCCURED-->'+e);
    } 
}
public static void updateLeadBack(lead l) {
    lead ld = new lead();
    ld.Id=l.id;
    ld.OwnerId=userinfo.getUserId();
    List<lead> updateLeadback = new List<lead>();
    updateLeadback.add(ld); 
    update updateLeadback;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updateLeadBack(leadRecord);  //call a method to update Owner with CurrentLoged in User
```

...

```
update updateLeadback;
```

Do not DML in a loop.

---

```
    if(updateLead.size()>0) {
        update updateLead;
    }
```

DML on an empty list is okay, and actually **faster** than checking yourself on a non-empty list. Just do:

```
update updateLead;
```

---

```
catch(exception e) {
    system.debug('EXCEPTION OCCURED-->'+e);
}
```

Do not try-catch if you don't intend to handle the error. Either let the exception throw, or, preferably, handle the errors in bulk:

```
    List<lead> updateLead = new List<lead>();
    List<lead> sourceLead = new List<Lead>();
    for(lead leadRecord:leadList) {
        lead oldlead =oldmap.get(leadRecord.id);
        // omitted if logic //
        updateLead.add(ls);
        sourceLead.add(leadRecord);
    }
    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(updateLead, false);
    for(Integer i = 0, s = results.size(); i < s; i++) {
      if(!results[i].isSuccess()) {
        sourceLead[i].addError('Error updating lead: '+results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
      }
    }
```

---

A Boolean is already a Boolean:

```
        else if(leadRecord.Need_Assistance__c== false){
```

should be just:

```
        else if(!leadRecord.Need_Assistance__c){
```

---

```
List<lead> updateLeadback = new List<lead>();
updateLeadback.add(ld); 
update updateLeadback;
```

If you ever need to update one record, just update it:

```
update ld;
```

No need to have a list of records (but note you should be using bulk updates here).

---

If you use a `before update` trigger instead of `after update`, you can update these fields without the need for a recursive DML operation (and need for the `isrun` flag).

Comment: Thanks sfdxFox.How can i avoid this statment out of for loop if(leadRecord.Need_Assistance__c== false){
                updateLeadBack(leadRecord);  //call a method to update Owner with CurrentLoged in User
            }

Comment: yes. i need my code run for bulk records

Comment: @sandy As I said, change your trigger to `before update`, and you don't need any of those DML operations.

Comment: thanks..will do that.

Comment: thanks for help.i like your way of help to others. learning many things from you.